# Airflow var.json masking

Tags: airflow

I configured Airflow (v 2.2.2) DAG to read variables from secrets backend. Variables are used by BashOperator via jinja template.

The problem is that I can't make variable masking to work using `var.json` syntax.

The following example works for me and password is masked in Airflow logs:

```
BashOperator(
    task_id='my_id',
    bash_command="some-command --user={{ var.value.MY_USER }} -- password={{ var.json.MY_PASSWORD }}",
    ...
)
```

Now I want to store username and password in the same variable. Credentials are retrieved, but unfortunately password is not masked in logs.

```
BashOperator(
    task_id='my_id',
    bash_command="some-command --user={{ var.json.VARIABLE_NAME_SECRET.user }} -- password={{ var.json.VARIABLE_NAME_SECRET.password }}",
    ...
)
```

Is it possible to mask value in dictionary when variable is retrieved already json-deserialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a bug in the masking method, instead, you can store your username and password in an airflow connection, then access them with the same method:

```py
BashOperator(
    task_id='my_id',
    bash_command="some-command --user={{ conn.connection_id.login }} -- password={{ conn.connection_id.password }}",
    ...
)
```

Comment: I will check it, but AFAIK Jinja accepts both syntax options

Comment: I have tried - the same result

Comment: You are right, I just tested it, and it seems that there is a bug or something missing, I updated my answer by proposing another method to achieve that

Comment: Thanks, the password was masked using Airflow connection.